# Downloading entire directories from ftp server with python3

Tags: python-3.x, download, ftp, urllib2, urllib

I've searched, yet not found a simplistic way to download a bunch of files from an ftp server (example: ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/subdaily/standard_format/).

I want to download all .zip or .txt files from that directory in one go to a local_path using python3. Any suggestions?